# Gas price per station dataset

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a dataset containing the following field:

- history of gas prices
- geolocation

---

I am mostly interested in the following locations:

- California, United States
- Massachusetts, United States
- Paris, France
- Seoul, South Korea

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about gas prices for Paris and Seoul, but there's a few different places you can get historical gas prices for areas in the U.S.

- The **Bureau of Labor Statistics** publishes monthly historical gas price data for major metropolitan areas, so you can compare the cost of gas in Boston in January 1978, for example, to the cost of gas in San Diego in that same month. BLS data is accessible from the BLS [source itself](http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/ap/), or you can access the same data from [Enigma Public](https://public.enigma.com/datasets/bls-average-price-data-gasoline/0e07731f-9ac9-403b-9b3e-2ebccdb537ac/?filter=%2B%5B%3Eseries_area_name%5B%22San%20Diego%22%20OR%20%22Boston%22%5D%5D) (table linked filtered for Boston and San Diego).
- The [**Energy Information Administration** also has historical gas price data](http://www.eia.gov/tools/faqs/faq.cfm?id=26&t=10Z).

[Disclosure: I work at Enigma. :D ]

Answer (score 3):

For Paris, you could go on http://www.prix-carburants.gouv.fr/rubrique/opendata/ for data per day and gas-station. You can get data up to 2007.

The European Commission is also publishing data by member states on a weekly basis in the [weekly oil bulletin](http://ec.europa.eu/energy/observatory/reports/List-of-WOB.pdf).